# passing a null pointer of an object into a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, object

If I have `class* object = NULL;`, and I pass `object` into `function(class* arg){arg = new class();}`, does `object = new class()`?

I ask because a pointer is just an address, right? So if I pass a NULL pointer as an argument and assign a new object to it, the address will be changed from zero, and the original pointer will not point to the new object, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the function, `arg` will point to the new object; but as you passed a *copy of the pointer*, once the function is over, it will not be accessible anymore, and `object` will not point to it (but still to NULL).

You need to pass either a reference to object (`class*&`), or a pointer to object (`class**`), to enable the function to modify it,

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. You passed `object` by value to the function. So changing the value in the function has no effect on `object`. If you wanted the function to be able to change `object`, you need to pass either a reference or a pointer to `object` to the function.